# Angular cli: reference a hashed scripts

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

## Custom webpack config @angular/cli 6

angular/cli 6 supports custom webpack config were one can specify a custom application bootstrap.

```
"projects": {
  "custom-name": {
    // ...
    "architect": {
      // ...
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-webpack:webpack",
        "options": {
          "webpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
        }
      }
    }
```

custom webpack config can be specified as such

```
 const path = require('path');
 const config = {
   entry: './src/custom-app.js',
   mode: 'production',
   output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
     filename: 'custom-app.js'
   }
 };
 module.exports = config;
```

then the output bundle can be reference in `angular.json`

```
"scripts": [
  { "input": "dist/custom-app.js", "lazy": true }
]
```

and then used as such

```
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const customApp = new Worker('custom-app.js');
  }
}
```

## Problem/Question

Caching might become a problem with the setup above! 
What if we need to hash the `custom-app.js` bundle using `hashcontent`?

```
 const path = require('path');
 const config = {
   entry: './src/custom-app.js',
   mode: 'production',
   output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
     filename: '[name][contenthash].js'
   }
 };
 module.exports = config;
```

This will no longer result in `custom-app.js` but instead something like `custom-app1247989898989.js`.

Is there a way to load the hashed file without having to store a hash at build time?

Any suggestion is welcome
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research this is what I found. 
This is a result of trying quite some suggestions from SO and Github...

First of all I had to change my `webpack.config.js` to add `contenthash` support

```
const path = require('path');
const config = {
  entry: './src/custom-app.js',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'custom-app.[contenthash].js'
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

In the output object, `custom-app` can be replaced with `[name]` in case of multiple entries.

Then I was able to include my hashed script using the snippet below

```
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const customApp = new Worker('custom-app.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.js);
  }
}
```

Where `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the hash of the file.

This has some drawbacks, for instance if I change the `custom-app` file, the hash will change and I need to reference the new hash...

But it works for me as I am changing my worker that much...

Answer (score -1):

You can try following flag to avoid the hashing

**ng build --prod --output-hashing none**

for more details visit this [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Comment: Actually, hashing is needed. 

"Caching might become a problem with the setup above! What if we need to hash the custom-app.js bundle using hashcontent?"

If I deactivate hashing, the bundle might change but the filename will remain the same so the browser will reuse the cached file.

Comment: In your shared hosting or wherever you have uploaded your dist folder, the first thing that's looked for is your main.xxxx.js. if you have renamed your main.xxxx.js then you need to upload your corresponding new dist folder too to make this deployment work. I hope you getting me.